# Run batch CODE in a vbscript file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to make a vbscript file that can run batch code (Note: Not a batch file, but batch code)

The code, which works in a batch file:

```
IF EXIST "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyManufacturer\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms" ( 
"%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyManufacturer\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms" 
) ELSE (start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b)
```

I can make the vbscript code almost do what I want using:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\myscript.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Now I would like to combine these two pieces of code into one file, so something along the lines of:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Exec "IF EXIST ""%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyManufacturer\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms"" (""%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyManufacturer\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms"") ELSE (start /b """" cmd /c del ""%~f0""&exit /b)" 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

However when I run this code I get `The system cannot find the file specified`. This is expected, since Exec (or Run, or Execute) runs a batch file and not batch code. So, is there a command similar to Exec that will run batch **code** and not a batch **file**?

Some extra info that I don't think is necessary to a solution (But included for the sake of completedness):

- This code is placed in the startup folder
- The code is created in C# in order to run a ClickOnce application on startup
- The reason I want to use vbscript is that the batch file opens a cmd window for a second, which is undesirable. My understanding is that the line `Set WshShell = Nothing` will make the command run invisibly
- I have tried including `>nul` at the end of each line of the batch file, since I read that it will stop the output. This did not work for me.
- It is theoretically possible for this to work by using both a .bat and a .vbs file, but this would require putting the .bat file in some other directory and feels generally hackish

I am open to other solutions besides vbscript, provided they can check if the .appref file exists, run the file if so, and delete itself if the file doesn't exist. This may be trivial in vbscript but I've never used vbscript before.

EDIT:
According to @Jason's comment, I have modified the code as follows. Now it runs with no output and without running my app (AKA it doesn't do $#!+)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /C ""IF EXIST ""%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyManufacturer\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms"" (""%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyManufacturer\MyClickOnceApp.appref-ms"") ELSE (start /b """" cmd /c del ""%~f0""&exit /b)", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: You would have to execute CMD.exe.

Comment: Can I pass my code as an argument to cmd.exe?

Comment: Use `CMD /C <your command>` as the execution command.

Comment: `Set WshShell = Nothing` won't make console window invisible. The only way to hide console is to set the 2nd parameter of `Run` method of `WScript.Shell` to 0, as @xs6 pointed.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Check the update. Still not able to make it work.

Comment: Why don't you write it directly in a bat or in the CMD, And `%~f0` is pointer to a file and not to a command. This will not work at all !

Comment: IMO, You are trying to solve more difficult question than just convert your batch code into VBScript.

Comment: @omegastripes Agreed. Unfortunately I guess it's time to learn some vbscript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the string in the path ! like this it work :

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c if exist test1.txt (echo ok & del test1.txt & pause) else (echo ko & pause)"
```

Try to work with 8.3 format. To resolve the composed-name and don't use string.

But if you're programming in VBS why do you want to use batch code in it ?

If you want to use both make a .BAT file. Or generate it from you're VBS and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example:

you have a batch called regex.bat :

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in (
  'netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr /rxc:"[ ]* SSID [ ]*: ..*"'
) do for /f "tokens=*" %%k in ("%%j") do set "SSID=%%k"
echo %SSID% > regex.txt
```

the vbs looks like this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WshShell.Run "regex.bat",0,True
```

This works for me fine. No cmd-Windows comes up. Hope this helpes you

Comment: Please re-read the question: This does work fine, I am looking for a way to put the batch code in the .vbs file

Comment: I have..but this is a fine workaround i wanted to show you this, but be more unfriendly :)